electron-builder makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE - no useful error?
I have an azure devops pipeline which uses electron-builder to package and publish a windows executable installer.  It worked until recently, with no changes made to code or pipeline it began to fail and no cause can be found.  I have the environment set to DEBUG=electron-builder to gather as much info as possible, but I'm still not seeing any useful error details.
Typically it would also do a --publish always  but I have removed that because the error occurs without it.
Are there steps I can take to gain more information?  Is there anything useful in the azure log here that I'm missing?
Command executed by the pipeline:
    $ ../node_modules/.bin/cross-env '../node_modules/.bin/electron-builder' --win --x64 --config.productName={{application}}-UAT --config.extraMetadata.name={{project}}{{application}}-uat --config.publish.repo={{project}}{{application}}-qa
Log Data from pipeline


Output: "/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{application}}-UAT-v0.0.179.exe"
Install: 0 pages (0 bytes), 1 section (32792 bytes), 28 instructions (784 bytes), 2925 strings (23926 bytes), 26 language tables (4316 bytes).
Uninstall: 4 pages (320 bytes), 1 section (32792 bytes), 1802 instructions (50456 bytes), 8509 strings (108758 bytes), 26 language tables (8684 bytes).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               57856 / 39424 bytes
Install code:                   9788 / 45834 bytes
Install data:                      0 / 8 bytes
Uninstall code+data:          124823 / 126184 bytes
CRC (0xDAF0DAE2):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                   192471 / 211454 bytes (91.0%)
  • exited          command=makensis code=0 pid=1783
  • spawning        command=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder wine --ia32 /__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{application}}-UAT-v0.0.179.exe
  • execute command  command=wine /__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{application}}-UAT-v0.0.179.exe workingDirectory=
  • command executed  executable=wine
                      errorOut=0034:err:module:process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe" not found
    002c:err:wineboot:process_run_key Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (126).
    00b8:err:explorer:initialize_display_settings Failed to query current display settings for L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1".
    
  • exited          command=app-builder code=0 pid=1784
  • spawning        command=/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis -WX -INPUTCHARSET UTF8 -DAPP_ID=com.electron.{{project}}{{application}}-uat -DAPP_GUID=dd09bf3b-f027-58f7-988b-89c7b457f575 -DUNINSTALL_APP_KEY=dd09bf3b-f027-58f7-988b-89c7b457f575 -DPRODUCT_NAME={{application}}-UAT -DPRODUCT_FILENAME={{application}}-UAT -DAPP_FILENAME={{application}}-UAT -DAPP_DESCRIPTION={{project}} {{application}} Client Application -DVERSION=0.0.179 -DPROJECT_DIR=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/www -DBUILD_RESOURCES_DIR=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/www/build -DAPP_PACKAGE_NAME={{project}}{{application}}-uat -DMUI_ICON=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/.icon-ico/icon.ico -DMUI_UNICON=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/.icon-ico/icon.ico -DAPP_64=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{project}}{{application}}-uat-0.0.179-x64.nsis.7z -DAPP_64_NAME={{project}}{{application}}-uat-0.0.179-x64.nsis.7z -DAPP_64_HASH=436CB5BA50C783C2102B9678AEF6A3E3334AE6D465BABB9C5989D5F5E546F0A23627FD1A6D397F0FD73C24A02930FC28465F55A5BAD2C8F97696A48B2DC96B46 -DCOMPANY_NAME={{company}} -DAPP_INSTALLER_STORE_FILE={{project}}{{application}}-uat-updater\installer.exe -DCOMPRESSION_METHOD=7z -DHIDE_RUN_AFTER_FINISH -DMULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_ALLOW_ELEVATION -DINSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS_REQUIRED -DallowToChangeInstallationDirectory -DMENU_FILENAME={{company}} -DSHORTCUT_NAME={{application}}-UAT -DUNINSTALL_DISPLAY_NAME={{application}}-UAT -DMUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp -DMUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp -DESTIMATED_SIZE=1061717 -DCOMPRESS=auto -DUNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/__uninstaller-nsis-{{project}}{{application}}-uat.exe -XOutFile "/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{application}}-UAT-v0.0.179.exe" -XVIProductVersion 0.0.179.0 -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 ProductName "{{application}}-UAT" -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 ProductVersion "0.0.179" -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 LegalCopyright "Copyright © 2024 {{company}}" -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 FileDescription "{{project}} {{application}} Client Application" -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 FileVersion "0.0.179.20240816.4" -XVIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 CompanyName "{{company}}" -XUnicode true -XSetCompressor zlib - cwd=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/node_modules/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis
Command line defined: "APP_ID=com.electron.{{project}}{{application}}-uat"
Command line defined: "APP_GUID=dd09bf3b-f027-58f7-988b-89c7b457f575"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_APP_KEY=dd09bf3b-f027-58f7-988b-89c7b457f575"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_NAME={{application}}-UAT"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_FILENAME={{application}}-UAT"
Command line defined: "APP_FILENAME={{application}}-UAT"
Command line defined: "APP_DESCRIPTION={{project}} {{application}} Client Application"
Command line defined: "APP_64=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/{{project}}{{application}}-uat-0.0.179-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64_NAME={{project}}{{application}}-uat-0.0.179-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64_HASH=436CB5BA50C783C2102B9678AEF6A3E3334AE6D465BABB9C5989D5F5E546F0A23627FD1A6D397F0FD73C24A02930FC28465F55A5BAD2C8F97696A48B2DC96B46"
Command line defined: "COMPANY_NAME={{company}}"
Command line defined: "APP_INSTALLER_STORE_FILE={{project}}{{application}}-uat-updater\installer.exe"
Command line defined: "COMPRESSION_METHOD=7z"
Command line defined: "HIDE_RUN_AFTER_FINISH"
Command line defined: "MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_ALLOW_ELEVATION"
Command line defined: "INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS_REQUIRED"
Command line defined: "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory"
Command line defined: "MENU_FILENAME={{company}}"
Command line defined: "SHORTCUT_NAME={{application}}-UAT"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_DISPLAY_NAME={{application}}-UAT"
Command line defined: "MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "ESTIMATED_SIZE=1061717"
Command line defined: "COMPRESS=auto"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE=/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/dist/__uninstaller-nsis-{{project}}{{application}}-uat.exe"
Processing script file: "<stdin>" (UTF8)
  • exited          command=makensis code=null pid=1847
  • async task error  error=/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null
  ⨯ /home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: /home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/__w/1/s/{{project}}-client/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:250:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Edit: New information with diagnostics
The only yellow flag I'm seeing is the disk space is pretty low, but it doesn't go to 0.  Should / Can I increase the agent disk space?
When electron-builder is executed, this information is provided
Most recent success:  electron-builder  version=22.8.0 os=6.5.0-1022-azure
Current failure: electron-builder  version=23.6.0 os=6.5.0-1025-azure
It also failed with electron-builder version 22.8, I tried updating that.  The os version is new though, I don't know how to control that or if that could be an issue.
Processing script file: "<stdin>" (UTF8)
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 39.74 MB out of 74244.74 MB, Memory: Used 911.00 MB out of 6921.00 MB, CPU: Usage 61.30%
  • exited          command=makensis code=null pid=1852
  • async task error  error=/home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null
  ⨯ /home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: /home/vsts_azpcontainer/.cache/electron-builder/nsis/nsis-3.0.4.1/linux/makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
null
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/__w/1/s/ethos-client/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:250:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
/__w/1/s/ethos-client
Mon Aug 19 14:28:50 UTC 2024

##[debug]Exit code 0 received from tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/bash'
##[debug]task result: Succeeded
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;done=true;]
##[debug]Handler exit code: 0



Hi Alex, you can start a new build by choosing Run pipeline and selecting Enable system diagnostics, Run or set the variable system.debug to true to make your logs to be more verbose. For more information, see Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues.

There have been no changes to the pipeline or code, but the pipeline began to fail recently. It's possible that there have been updates to the software, task, or agent versions. You can compare the logs from successful and failed runs to see if different versions are being used.  Additionally, try executing the relevant commands locally and manually to check if there will be the same error, which can help narrow down the issue to determine if it's related to the Azure DevOps pipeline.  By the way, can you please share your YAML to let us know which tasks you are using?

I have updated with new information from enabling diagnostics and system.debug.  The only yellow flag I'm seeing is the disk space is pretty low, but it doesn't go to 0.  Should / Can I increase the agent disk space?

@MiaoTian-MSFT I also added information about the azure os referenced when electron-builder starts, it is different from the last successful run, maybe an issue?  That and/or the disk space being low?

Hi @Alex, thanks for your update. According to your log, 39.74 MB out of 74244.74 MB, it seems that the available space is very low. Low disk space may indeed cause issues. And the total space is greater than 10 GB, so you are using the Self hosted agent. Because the Microsoft-hosted agent does not have such a large space. You can try to increase the disk space of the current Self hosted agent or reconfigure a new Self hosted agent on a machine with larger disk space.

You can login to the self-hosted agent and try executing the commands manually to check if there will be the same error. By the way, I searched the error makensis process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  in the electron-builder issue list, you can check the issues and try the possible solutions there. Or you can also create a new issue for this question :)

Thanks @MiaoTian-MSFT Are you sure the agent isn't Microsoft hosted?  I'm using "pool: vmImage: ubuntu-latest" which is referenced on the microsoft hosted agent docs.    If it is self-hosted, how would I increase disk space?  I see some instructions for linux self hosted agents but I have a windows machine, and I don't see how to upload it to azure after configuration either.  Thanks!!

@MiaoTian-MSFT  I also have a container specified, so do I need to somehow increase the agent disk size, or the container, or both?  pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest
container: neb-electron-builder

@MiaoTian-MSFT  I also just noticed that the first diagnostic message in the pipeline shows the disk space as: Disk: / Available 18837.13 MB out of 74244.74 MB.  I'm wondering why its already staring with such a low amount instead of the full amount.

Hi @Alex, according to the update, you are indeed using the Microsoft-hosted agent. I'm sorry that I mistakenly thought you were using the self-hosted agent. I tested and found that the total space of ubuntu-latest image is 74244 MB, and the free space is about 18000 MB. This is consistent with the official document that Microsoft-hosted agents have at least 10 GB of free disk space available for your pipelines to run. I guess the occupied space should be some pre-installed software.

I realized that you are using container in the pipeline. Please check if your container image has been updated recently. If it is updated recently, you can use an old successful version of the container image to see if the pipeline can run successfully.

The disk size of the container depends on the space of the agent you are using, and as we cannot change the free disk space of Microsoft hosted agent, to increase the disk space, please consider the self-hosted agent. You said that you only have a Windows machine, maybe you can create a Linux Azure virtual machine with enough space and configure the Linux self-hosted agent on it.

@MiaoTian-MSFT The issue appears to be fixed by using vmImage: ubuntu-20.04.  This is confusing because ubuntu-latest has been the same 22.04 version since 2022 according to [this post, yet only recently did we start having issues.  I'm concerned what will happen when Microsoft stops hosting 20.04 agents.  THANK YOU very much for all your help!!  Do you want to post an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Hi @Alex, thanks for your update and glad to hear that the issue is fixed currently.  Based your solution, I tested ubuntu-20.04 and ubuntu-22.04 images in my pipeline. I found that the free space of ubuntu-20.04 images seems to be 1G more than the free space on ubuntu-22.04 images. I guess it may be that the software versions on ubuntu-22.04 images are newer, which causes more space to be occupied.  Maybe this 1G difference is the key to the problem. You can compare the Current image version recorded by the Initialize job in the successful and failed runs on ubuntu-latest image.

According to the discussion in our comments, we found that the issue may have been caused by low disk space on the Microsoft-hosted agent and potential changes in the container image or agent image version. We tried enabling system diagnostics and setting system.debug to true for more verbose logs. We also compared logs from successful and failed runs and checked for updates in the container image.
Finally, you solved the issue by switching the vmImage from ubuntu-latest to ubuntu-20.04. This change resolved the pipeline failures.
I tested ubuntu-20.04 and ubuntu-22.04 images in my pipeline. I found that the free space of ubuntu-20.04 images seems to be 1G more than the free space on ubuntu-22.04 images. I guess it may be that the software versions on ubuntu-22.04 images are newer, which causes more space to be occupied.
